# Internal microphone "Front Left" self adjusting to 100% (equal to front right ) from 0 leading to not recording my voice [Ubuntu 20.04, Lenovo 330]

Tags: pulseaudio, lenovo, alsa, microphone, pavucontrol

My microphone is not working in ubuntu 20.04.
I followed the tutorial https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-ubuntu-20-04-lenovo-ideapad-microphone-not-working/ and have made changes as and when required.
I have also gone to **pavucontrol** and made **front left** to 0. When it is at 0 (or there is a difference between the front left and front right , my voice is captured). However, it is auto adjusting itself (this auto adjustment is random) and it becomes equal to **front right** . As a result of which only static noise is captured in the microphone and not my voice.

How do I make this change stick.

Comment: were you able to make it work?

Comment: No. It still auto adjusts. Previously I was able to use headphones and communicate but now it auto adjusts in it also .

Comment: I also had the exact same problem, i had to change to fedora and use firefox to be able to do my job.